# How to ignore Nodata value in symbology (stretched) and raster statistics in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, nodata

I have a raster with its nodata value defined as -9999. however, for its symbology method and statistics, the -9999 is not ignored by ArcMap. How can I make ArcMap acknowledge the nodata value of -9999?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is odd which would suggest some sort of corruption with the dataset. Run the Get Raster properties tool and get it to return the minimum value, is it as expected or is it returning -9999 as the minimum value? Try running the calculate statistics tool on your data to see if it correctly identifies the min/max of your dataset.

Where did this dataset come from? Can you share it, if none of the above fix it?